# Failed to load ASPNET Core runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

ok so i made a project in VS 2019 and decided to upgrade to VS 2022 and i keep getting this error message everytime i try to run my webApp. I tried to disable SSL but it didnt work for this project. i also tried to install the correct versions for example i used version 3.19 in this project after installing this version it didn't help?

---

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Looks like the app is looking for ASP.Net Core 5 but it doesn't look like you have it installed.

Comment: What do you see when you run `dotnet --list-sdks` and `dotnet --list-runtimes`?

Comment: @phuzi thank you after installing ASP.NET Core 5.0 Runtime it worked. i just never had this problem before so cheers mate.